# Rails 5: How Do I Find Out Which Gem Depends on a Specific Ruby Version?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, ruby-on-rails-5, rvm

I work on a Mac Mini Server running the latest version of High Sierra. I use Ruby Version Manager.

I recently installed Ruby 2.7.1p83 and upgraded all of my Rails apps to the latest versions of 5.0, 5.1 and 5.2.

I decided to clean my rubies and only have Ruby version Ruby 2.7.1p83.

Now when I go to some of my Rails app folders in the terminal, I see the following messages:

```
Required ruby-2.5.2 is not installed.
To install do: 'rvm install "ruby-2.5.2"'
```

Is there a terminal command that I can execute where I can find out Ruby dependencies for gems? Gems are the only place I think may be causing the problem since the message doesn't appear for all my folders.

Comment: It seems like not a gem dependencies, but `.rvmrc`, `.ruby-version`, `.ruby-gemset` or `.versions.conf` files under your projects root folders. Also check your Gemfiles for `ruby-2.5.2` string.

Comment: @cnnr please make your comment an answer and I will check it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your case seems like not a gem dependencies, but like you have ruby version definition somewhere in your apps code.

Check this files under your projects root folders:

- .rvmrc
- .ruby-version
- .ruby-gemset
- .versions.conf

And also check your Gemfiles for string `ruby-2.5.2`.

Comment: My newer applications don't have those old RVM files. Several of them had .ruby-version files with string 'ruby-2.5.2'. When I deleted the files the message didn't appear anymore.